# Dynamic ID Selenium Python Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I'm trying to do a test automation on Amazon site and so far so good except this part where the ID dynamically changes.

What I'm trying to do is to click the next button on the Sponsored Products section.

Here is my code

```
first_product="https://www.amazon.com/Love-KANKEI-Floating-Shelves-Bathroom-Carbonized/dp/B07XDHK395/ref=sr_1_18?dchild=1&keywords=rustic+wood&qid=1600334401&sr=8-18"
first_product_xpath = "//*[@id='a-autoid-21']"

first_sponsored_products = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sp_detail-none']/div[1]/div[1]/h2")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", first_sponsored_products)
time.sleep(2)
select_first_next_sponsored = driver.find_element_by_xpath(first_product_xpath)
select_first_next_sponsored.click()
```

[image]

I can't think of what other approach to use since this button I'm trying to click doesn't seem to have anything unique except the ID and it dynamically changes so I had to check again and again the current ID and hope that it would not change again on the next run of the script.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reasons, I'm unable to view sponsored items div in my chrome. So I tried for "Customers who viewed this item also viewed" div. For this section div id is "desktop-dp-sims_session-similarities-sims-feature" & your next button contains the class name of "a-carousel-goto-nextpage". So we can try something like this,

```
first_product_xpath = "//div[@id='desktop-dp-sims_session-similarities-sims-feature']//a[contains(@class, 'a-carousel-goto-nextpage')]"
```

So update the corresponding div id for "Sponsored products related to this items" div & try.

Comment: Hi thank you for giving me the idea, it's working now when i used "//div[@id='sp_detail-none']//a[contains(@class, 'a-button a-button-image a-carousel-button a-carousel-goto-nextpage')]"

Answer (score 1):

This xpath gives you all the products on that session

`//div[@id="sp_detail-none"]/descendant::li`

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, i was confused which div should I be using and you got it right. Thanks again!